# JavaScript not beign executed due to parent div being hidden on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery GalleryView plugin. I've use the plugin on one page and contained it in a div with the appropriate code which sends the div's id to the external GalleryView .js file.

I'm also using jQuery to hide the div on document ready, so the users can toggle the visibility, but for some reason when the div is hidden innitially, the gallery does not load correctly. I believe this may be because the script inside the code is not being called due to it's hidden status.

I hope I have explained this clearly enough. Does anyone have any ideas?

The plugin home page can be found [here](http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview) or I believ the [jQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/galleryview) page is more up to date but not as well documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the gallery has issues calculating widths/height because the elemens are hidden ..

you should either hide the elements after the gallery has initialized, or move it off-screen by CSS (initially) and once the gallery initializes, hide it and bring it back to its position..

***Update***
(*after comments and inspecting the plugin source code*)

The issue is definitely the hiding of the containing div by you at document ready event.
The true problem is that the plugin executes its code at `window load` and not `dom ready`, meaning after the images have loaded..

If you hide it before it gets executed, the plugin `fails` to correctly identify some properties of the images like width/height etc..

If the space the gallery occupies is the same whether it is hidden or show, then i would suggest that instead of hiding the container, to set `visibility:hidden`. This does not skew the properties of the images like the `display:none` does (*its is what `.hide()` uses*)

so

```
$(document).ready(){
  // hide container
  $('#container').css('visibility','hidden');
  // plugin init call here
  $('#id').galleryView({...});
}
```

If you need the gallery to dissapear and also free its space when hidden, then you need to call the hiding, after the plugin has completed its initialization..

```
$(document).ready(){
  // plugin init call here 
  $('#id').galleryView({...});
}

$(window).load(){
  // your code to hide the container of the gallery
  // we use timeout to give some time for the gallery code to execute first..
  setTimeout(function(){ $('#containerid').hide(); }, 100 );
}
```

Comment: How would I hide them only when the gallery has initialized?

Comment: assuming your run something like this `$('#id').galleryView({...});` chain the hide to it like this `$('#id').galleryView({...}).hide();`. If you can point me to the page of the plugin you use i could be more specific..

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've updated the question with a link to the plugin's home page.

Comment: @Gaby Previously the gallery was getting stuck on the loading bar. If I chain the .hide() like you said, it loads the first image of the gallery, but the rest of the javascript seems to feel and it loads no menu. Not sure why.

Comment: Gaby, yes that works perfectly! Thank you so much for the help, you've saved me much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

Comment: This functionality supported by jquery core since 1.4 - .live() method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that js does not "see" the content of elements with `display: none;`

The easiest solution: use position hiding instead of `display: none;`

Html:

```
<div class="hidden">...</div>
```

Css:

```
.hidden {
  position: absolute !important;
  left: -9999px !important;
  top: -9999px !important;
}
```

And in js `.addClass('hidden')` and .`removeClass('hidden')` to hide or show the element

In this case this element will be "visible" for js and images to load, but hidden from user.